# Load Default Dump file using Pig

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig

which is the PigStorage() need to use to get the load the file for the following query

```
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY 'doop'
select a.* from cdr.cell_tower_info
```

the output for the above query is like this

`Haryana Ambala  404 20  80  37591   76.76746    30.373488   404-20-80-37591
Haryana Ambala  404 20  80  30021   76.76746    30.373488   404-20-80-30021
Haryana Ambala  404 20  80  37591   76.76746    30.373488   404-20-80-37591`

I am working with CDR analysis where first i need to retrieve some fields from a table using select and save it into a HDFS folder , this result is again need to load using pig for further analysis

Comment: initially table (cdr.cell_tower_info) is in hive???

Comment: @KishoreKumarSuthar yes the table is at Hcatlog

Comment: You want to load the above data in pig and print as each field right?

Comment: I need to Load the above result into Pig for further analysis

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE cell_tower_info
   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
   LOCATION 'doop'
   AS
SELECT .* from cdr.cell_tower_info
```

Comment: it showing error like external table is not able to create at a location

Answer (score 0):

Hive default delimiter is ctrl-A (\001).

I think PigStorage('\001') should work to use the Hive output data in PIG.

Alternatively Hive table can be defined as **fields terminated by '\t'** , so that the result can be used directly in PIG.

Comment: A = LOAD '/user/hue/doop' using PigStorage('\001');
B = foreach A generate $8 as cell_id;
dump B;

the above query is which i tried and i am getting an error like

org.apache.pig.PigServer - exception during parsing: Error during parsing. <file script.pig, line 1, column 45>  Unexpected character '0'

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?
**input.txt**

```
Haryana Ambala  404 20  80  37591   76.76746    30.373488   404-20-80-37591
Haryana Ambala  404 20  80  30021   76.76746    30.373488   404-20-80-30021
Haryana Ambala  404 20  80  37591   76.76746    30.373488   404-20-80-37591
```

**PigScript:**

```
A = LOAD 'input.txt' AS line;
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(line,'\\s+')) AS (f1:chararray,f2:chararray,f3:int,f4:int,f5:int,f6:int,f7:double,f8:double,f9:chararray);
C = FOREACH B GENERATE f1,f2,f8,f9;
DUMP C;
```

**Output:**

```
(Haryana,Ambala,30.373488,404-20-80-37591)
(Haryana,Ambala,30.373488,404-20-80-30021)
(Haryana,Ambala,30.373488,404-20-80-37591)
```

Comment: (HaryanaAmbala40420803759176.7674630.373488404-20-80-37591,,,)
(HaryanaAmbala40420803002176.7674630.373488404-20-80-30021,,,)
(HaryanaAmbala40420803759176.7674630.373488404-20-80-37591,,,)

is the result i am getting while running the query 
that it taking entire column as a single string

Comment: For me its working fine for the given input not sure why its not working for you. Alright, can you check your input file and let me know what is delimiter of each whitespace. If you are using windows, open your input file in notepad++ and check the hidden delimiters under notepad++->View->ShowSymbol. If you are using MAC OS you can use sublimetext or Textmate editors view-->show Invisible characters. This will help us to see what could be the actual delimiter.

Comment: In unix you can use ":set list" command in vim and check the whitespace characters.

Answer (score 0):

if your data is stored in hive table then,

```
X = LOAD 'hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hive/warehouse/input.txt' using PigStorage('\t')  AS line;
Y = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(line,'\\s+')) AS (A1:chararray,A2:chararray,A3:int,A4:int,A5:int,A6:int,A7:double,a8:double,A9:chararray);
Z = FOREACH B GENERATE A1,A2,A8,A9;
DUMP Z;
```

in my case port is 9000. give according to your system.